# How to ensure images all loaded before I reference in my HTML canvas

Tags: html

I want to draw some images in on a HTML canvas with

```
context.drawImage(Im1 ,205,18,184,38);
```

In order to make sure it loads I need to put in code like this but then I cannot draw things with it

```
var Im1 = new Image();
Im1.src="rechnung11014page1/img/1/Im1.png";
Im1.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(Im1 ,205,18,184,38);
}
```

Is there a way to load all the images and then execute a block of code using several images?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript there is the body onload method.  Just create an event handler for it and run your drawing code there.  OnLoad is called after all of the page elements are loaded.

Of course, it would also require that you directly reference those images somewhere in the body of your html.  If they aren't already there, you could easily create a hidden div to do the loading.

Comment: [Adding since it's so common] If you happen to be using jQuery, see [$(document).ready vs. $(window).load](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

Answer (score 0):

You can load all your images using a fn like one defined below which calls draw fn when all the images are loaded...

```
function loadImages()
{
    var imgToLoad = 3, imgLoaded = 0;

    var onImgLoad = function()
    {
        imgLoaded++;
        if(imgLoaded == imgToLoad)
            drawFromLoadedImages();
    };

    Img1 = new Image();
    Img1.src = 'images/x.png';
    Img1.onload = onImgLoad;

    Img2 = new Image();
    Img2.src = 'images/y.png';
    Img2.onload = onImgLoad;

    Img3 = new Image();
    Img3.src = 'images/z.png';
    Img3.onload = onImgLoad;
}
```

The above fn ensures that all 3 images are loaded before calling the draw function on the images.

Very old Question but hope this technique helps to anyone else coming to this question

Comment: Thanks for completing my question

Comment: Since this Q is old... you must have figured out a way as well.
How did you solved it?

Comment: I load it on a tag as invisible 
<img id="Im1_1" src="01/img/01/Im1.png" alt="Im1_1" width="382" height="790" style="display: none" />
<img id="Im2_1" src="01/img/01/Im2.png" alt="Im2_1" width="142" height="29" style="display: none" />