# Javascript function to fire after images have finished loading (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, image, html, object

I have the following code (the relevant parts):

```
window.addEventListener("load", loadImages, false);

var imgl = new Array();

function loadImages() {
    var img = [
        "img1",
        "img2",
        "img3",
        "etc"
    ];
    imgl[img.length-1].onload = function () {
        alert();
        initialise();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        imgl[img[i]] = new Image();
        imgl[img[i]].src = "img/"+img[i]+".png";
    }
}

function initialise() {
    //...
}
```

and I want to fire the `initialise()` function after all the images have finished loading, but nothing I tried worked. (Btw the `alert()` in the example is for testing, and I'm not getting it.) Why is this wrong? Other methods of doing this are also appreciated.

also I don't want to use jQuery, only if absolutely unavoidable.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The following doesn't work either, although making more sense:

```
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        imgl[img[i]] = new Image();
    }
    imgl[imgl.length-1].onload = function () {
        initialise();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        imgl[img[i]].src = "img/"+img[i]+".png";
    }
```

Comment: If that wasn't it, my suggestion would be to re-think the way you're using `onload`. [I don't think][1] you can apply `onload` to to a variable of type `Image`. Variables aren't loaded, they're initialized. What are you trying to do there anyways?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021990/how-to-ensure-images-all-loaded-before-i-reference-in-my-html-canvas, which gives a good answer without using jQuery

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot... sry for the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

`imgl[img.length-1]` doesn't exist, therefore cannot have an "onload" property.

You initialize `img1` at the beginning, but never populate it.

In other words:
`img.length-1` = 3

`img1[3]` doesn't exist.

I'm getting the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of undefined

Comment: yes I see what you mean, I tried something that you are suggesting (detailed in the EDIT) but it still didn1t work. btw its "imgL" for loaded